# Next 13 - gzip by default but not applying to some files

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, gzip, next.js13

On the documentation, it says that Next.js provides gzip compression by default. But why are this two files not being compress? its because of a size limit?

[image]

Comment: They might be so small that they can't be compressed further?